# Java: ArrayOutOfBounds side effect?

Tags: java, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm writing a Java program for the Common Meeting Times problem.  I read in integers from a text file and stored them in a master ArrayList.  The text file looks like so, where the first number of each line indicates the number of elements on that line (excluding itself):

```
6 6 7 2 4 5 9
5 1 3 4 8 7 
9 10 12 11 9 8 4 3 2 6
```

I then needed to create an ArrayList for each line of the text file, so I have three ArrayLists that I will ultimately be using for the CMT problem.  It seems that the code I wrote works, and gets each line into its own array, but I have some weird stuff going on inside the second while loop...

```
package brt2356.CMT;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestCMT {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        ArrayList<Integer> array1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> array2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> array3 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int value = 0; // first item in each line of text file
        int items = 0; // counter for while loop

        Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new File("C:/Users/me/workspace/cmt.txt"));

        ArrayList<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // master array

        /* Read in values from file to master array */
        while(inFile.hasNextInt()) {
            temp.add(inFile.nextInt());
        }
        inFile.close();

        value = temp.get(0); // first element of the first line in text file
        while(temp != null) {
            for(int i = 0; i < value; i++) {
                array1.add(temp.get(i + 1));
                items++;
            }
            System.out.println(array1 + " " + items + " " + value);
            value = temp.get(items + 1); // first element of second line
            for(int i = 0; i < value; i++) {
                array2.add(temp.get(items + 2));
                items++;
            }
            System.out.println(array2 + " " + items + " " + value);
            value = temp.get(items + 2); // first element of third line
            for(int i = 0; i < value; i++) {
                array3.add(temp.get(items + 3));
                items++;
            }
            System.out.println(array3);
        }
    }
}
```

I added some print statements in the while loop to make sure I was getting the correct values into each array.

The problem I am running into an IndexOutOfBoundsException and some extra printing.  The program behaves like it has an extra print statement... it's very weird.  I imagine that if I fix the IndexOutOfBoundsException, then the other problem will go away.

Example output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 30, Size: 23
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
    at brt2356.CMT.TestCMT.main(TestCMT.java:34)
[6, 7, 2, 4, 5, 9] 6 6
[1, 3, 4, 8, 7] 11 5
[10, 12, 11, 9, 8, 4, 3, 2, 6]
[6, 7, 2, 4, 5, 9, 6, 7, 2, 4, 5, 9, 5, 1, 3] 29 9
```

Comment: Can you please post the output?

Comment: Where do you set temp to null? You use that in your second while ... which you do not need at all.

Comment: I never set temp to null.  I guess I should do that at the end of the loop?

Comment: No just remove the while.

Comment: That worked.  I'll add the answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the second while loop (credit to Fildor).

```
    value = temp.get(0);

    for(int i = 0; i < value; i++) {
        array1.add(temp.get(i + 1));
        items++;
    }
    System.out.println(array1 + " " + items + " " + value);
    value = temp.get(items + 1);
    for(int i = 0; i < value; i++) {
        array2.add(temp.get(items + 2));
        items++;
    }
    System.out.println(array2 + " " + items + " " + value);
    value = temp.get(items + 2);
    for(int i = 0; i < value; i++) {
        array3.add(temp.get(items + 3));
        items++;
    }
    System.out.println(array3);
```